# C++ Error while attempting to recursivly return string

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I get this error while trying to compile:

> "terminate called after throwing an instance of '`std::out_of_range`'
>   `what()`: `basic_string::at` This application has requested the Runtime to
>   terminate it in an unusual way."

My guess is it has to do with the word.at() part of the program, but I cant seem to figure out why specifically.

```
string Recursive4(const string word)
{
    string D;
    int num = word.length();
    D.reserve(word.size());
    D += word.at(num);
    num--;
    if (word.at(0))
        return D;
    else
        return Recursive4(word);
}

int main()
{
    cout << Recursive4("Loyce") << endl;
}
```

Comment: The position for `word.at();` must be less than `word.size()`. You are passing `word.size()`.

Comment: `length()` and `size()` mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`string`, like nearly all containers, uses zero-indexing, so the maximum element index is `size-1`.  You could just change your code as follows:

```
string Recursive4(const string word)
{
    string D;
    int num = word.length() - 1;
    D.reserve(word.size());
    D += word.at(num);
    num--;
    if (word.at(0))
        return D;
    else
        return Recursive4(word);
}
```

EDIT:  As user657267 pointed out, `string` does return a reference to a `null` character if you use `operator[]` to get the element at index `size`.

Comment: For `at` this holds true, but `word[word.size()]` is well-defined for C++11 and returns an unmodifiable null character.

Comment: This fixed the error, but now it only outputs "e" and not the rest of the string, my guess is because int num gets re initialized during each recursive call? What do you all think?

Comment: @VividDebugger Why not use your debugger?

Comment: I apologize, I just could not understand the information my debugger output. The solution to the initial error has been fixed, and i'm super grateful, now the only issue is with the logic of my program

Comment: @VividDebugger You are creating a new string D on every call, and either returning the whole word, or a single character `word.at(num)`. Shouldn't you pass the string D along with the original word?

Comment: You are right! I figured it out after thinking hard on it for about an hour, but I've got the program working :)